# sql server transaccion y concurrencia

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

mi consulta es la siguiente con respecto a sql server:

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que anula un ingreso y el mismo realiza lo siguiente:

1. Actualiza el campo Estado de la Tabla Ingreso a Anulado.
2. Actualiza el campo stock de la tabla artículos restándole la cantidad de la tabla detalle_ingreso para volverlo al stock anterior.

Mi consulta es si estoy controlando bien la concurrencia en el primer update donde comparo con la versión del registro y si la transacción de ambos update están tratadas correctamente en el catch.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[ingreso_anular]
@idingreso int,
@LockID bigint
as
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    update ingreso set estado='Anulado'
    where idingreso=@idingreso AND convert(bigint,lock_id) = @LockID
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El ingreso ha sido anulado recientemente!',16,1)
    END

    update articulo
    set stock = stock - d.cantidad
    from articulo p
    inner join
    (select idarticulo,cantidad from detalle_ingreso where idingreso = @idingreso) d
    on p.idarticulo = d.idarticulo
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @Err varchar(1000)
        set @Err = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        RAISERROR(@Err, 16,1)           
END CATCH
```

No tengo mucha experiencia con transact y les agradezco por su tiempo de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la pregunta está un poco mal enfocada.

> Mi consulta es si estoy controlando bien la concurrencia en el primer
> update donde comparo con la versión del registro

No la concurrencia, la tienes que controlar por transacción. Has abierto una transacción con el nivel de aislamiento que tenga por defecto la base de datos (normalmente read uncommitted), y con ese nivel, puedes tener transacciones simultaneas que te realicen cosas inesperadas. La update para poder hacer su trabajo, conllevará implícita una lectura de la tabla, o de los índices para encontrar los registros que tiene que bloquear o modificar.

```
Create table ingreso
             (
             idingreso int identity(1, 1) primary key
           , estado    varchar(100)
           , lock_id   int
             );
go

insert into ingreso(estado
                  , lock_id)
values
       ( 'Otro', 1 ),
       ( 'Otro', 2 ),
       ( 'Anulado', 3 ),
       ( 'Anulado', 4 );
go
```

Ahora hacemos una update sobre la tabla, con lo mismo que hace el procedimiento.

```
set statistics profile on;
declare @IDINGRESO int
      , @LOCKID    bigint;

Set @IDINGRESO = 1;
Set @LOCKID = 1;

update ingreso
       set estado = 'Anulado'
where idingreso = @IDINGRESO AND convert(bigint, lock_id) = @LOCKID;

set statistics profile off;
```

[image: Resultado]

De la ejecución se puede ver que la búsqueda en el Indice y la conversión, son separadas de la ejecución de la actualización del índice y de la actualización del dato.

Además, aunque libres la primera update, la modificación de la segunda tabla, debiera de estar también afectada por la misma transacción ¿o no?, no obstante, dado que tocas tres tablas que seguro son importantes, es posible que en un entorno de concurrencia, mejorase mucho los tiempos, sacar de ese procedimiento la modificación de stock de artículos a otro. De manera que puedas procesar la transacción de ingresos por un lado, y al retorno procesar la modificación del stock, ya que no tendrías tres bloqueos simultáneos. Pero es sólo una opinión.

Te he cambiado la segunda update, porque me parece que no tienes porque hacer una tabla derivada, para algo que puedes relacionar directamente.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[ingreso_anular] 
(
    @idingreso int,
    @LockID bigint
)
as
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    -- Porque convertir todos los valores de una columna a un párámetro. 
    -- Lo suyo será convertir el parámetro en el tipo de dato de la columna
    update ingreso set estado='Anulado'
        where idingreso=@idingreso AND convert(bigint,lock_id) = @LockID

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El ingreso ha sido anulado recientemente!',16,1)
    END

    update articulo
        set stock = stock - d.cantidad
            from articulo p
                inner join detalle_Ingreso d on d.idarticulo = p.articulo
            where d.idIngreso = @idingreso;
    
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        DECLARE @Err varchar(1000);
        
        set @Err = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        RAISERROR(@Err, 16,1);   
        
END CATCH
```

> y si la transacción
> de ambos update están tratadas correctamente en el catch.

Si esta bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo, gran respuesta!!!